# HP ALM 12.01: How to do a mapping of Requirement -> Scenarios -> Test Cases?

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm, hp-alm-12.01

I have mapped Requirement to Test Cases in ALM.  There is a need in my current project to map Requirement to Scenarios and then map Scenarios to Test Cases.

Here is an example:

```
Req1 -> Scenario1 -> TestCase1
Req1 -> Scenario1 -> TestCase2
Req1 -> Scenario1 -> TestCase3
```

I tried creating this structure in ALM.  I put 'Scenario1' under 'Req1' in requirements tab and mapped all 3 Test Cases to 'Scenario1' (both 'Req1' and 'Scenario1' are created as 'Functional).

When all the Test Cases are 'Passed', I see 'Scenario1' getting updated as 'Passed' but 'Req1' is still in 'Not Covered' status.

[image]

Do I have to also map all the Test Cases to 'Req1' as well?  or Is there any other cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a functional requirement the Direct Cover Status depend on the test coverage for the same requirement.

In your example you have a functional requirement Req1 without test coverage and two requirement Scenario1 and Scenario2 with test coverage. The test coverage of Scenario1 and Scenario2 are not added to Req1 because they are not direct coverage tests.

You can add the same tests that cover the Scenario1 and Scenario2 in the Test Coverage of Req1 or you can change the Requirement Type of Req1 to Group or Folder. Group and Folder don't have a direct coverage but, if you switch to the Coverage Analisys (from View > Coverage Analisys) they show a bar with the aggregation of the statuses of the requirement that they contains.

Answer (score 1):

Status of the requirement is automatically changed to `Passed` when all test cases from test set are passed, all test cases that cover the requirement are in this test set.

It's easy to do: when you add tests to the test set, select `Requirements tree` tab >> select the requirement >> press `Add all tests that cover this requirement`.

[image]

And do not forget that after execution off test set you should refresh requirements table to see the change of a status:

[image]

Comment: I have added a picture to explain my question in a better way.  I have 'Req1' as the master requirement.  'Scenario1' and 'Scenario2' are child requirements.  'Req1' don't have test cases mapped as such.  'Scenario1' and 'Scenario2' has cases mapped.  I wanted to see if there is any way by which 'Req1' can get mapped to 'Scenario1' and 'Scenario2'.